# Check call static method php

Tags: php

i have class look like this:

```
class Foo
{
    puclic static function blindPaths($paths)
    {
        foreach($paths as $name=>$path)
        {
             $method='set'.ucfirst($name).'Path';
             if(method_exists(????,$method))
                 self::$method($path);
        }
    }

    public function setBasePath($base)
    {
       //do something...
    }

    public function setAppPath($app)
    {
       //do something...
    }

    ....
}
```

now, i call:

```
$paths = array(
    'base'=>'path.of.base.path',
    'app'=>'path.of.app.path',
    'someValue'=>'path.of.someValuePath',
    ....
);
Foo::blindPaths($paths);
```

problem when check method_exists, what to fill in those marks "????" somebody can help me?

Comment: [TFM](http://php.net/method_exists) has examples.

Comment: ^--« You're a poet and didn't even know it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(method_exists(__CLASS__, $method))
```

Answer (score 1):

In a simple, single class situation you could use the `__CLASS__` constant as a first argument for the `method_exists` call, but if you're in a situation where the static method is defined at the parent level (or an abstract class, or some place else), then perhaps you may want to consider this:

```
puclic static function blindPaths($paths)
{
    $current = get_called_class();
    foreach($paths as $name=>$path)
    {
        $method='set'.ucfirst($name).'Path';
        if(method_exists($current,$method))
            self::$method($path);
    }
}
```

Or, if you add interfaces and `Trait`'s to the mix:

```
puclic static function blindPaths($paths)
{
    $current = get_called_class();
    $current = new $current;//create instance
    foreach($paths as $name=>$path)
    {
        $method='set'.ucfirst($name).'Path';
        if($current instanceof Foo)
            self::$method($path);
        elseif ($current instanceof Bar)
            return $this->{$method}($path);
    }
}
```

But either way, rethink your design. If you're using a construct similar to what you have now, 9 out of 10 times, you're barking up the wrong tree.